# How to adjust selectedmeasure() for different dates based on what's been entered in a slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a lot of measures in my Power BI report. Here's an example of one:

```
count = 
VAR V_year = SELECTEDVALUE(table_1[YEAR])
VAR V_month = SELECTEDVALUE(table_1[MONTH])
RETURN
CALCULATE(COUNT(table_1[COLUMN_1]), 
table_1[YEAR] = V_year, 
table_1[MONTH] = V_month)
```

This counts up the values from column_1 in table_1 where the year and month columns match what has been selected in a couple of slicers. The month column is a 3-digit text string, e.g. 'OCT'. The year column is a 4 digit integer, e.g. '2023'.

When a user selects year and month, I want the report to display not just the selected year and month's result, but also the previous year's result for the same month, and the 3 year average for the same month.

I could do this by creating additional measures, but doing that for everything I need will require 200+ measures. I'm told I can use a calculation group to reduce the number of measures needed.

I understand that I can set up a calculation item within the calculation group like this, and that this will display the result from the measure above (or any other measure I apply it to):

```
total = SELECTEDMEASURE()
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this for the previous year or the 3 year average. Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: Suggest you have a look at [Introducing Calculation Groups](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculation-groups/)